# Issue in installing Arduino unit library and running with Firmata test application

Tags: arduino-uno, firmata

I am trying to update the Arduino library via the library manager and I tried to download it from the link given in the firmata_test program:

> WARNING: Category '' in library ArduinoUnit is not valid. Setting to
>   'Uncategorized'
>   C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_c8217a5b56c170d64dfe4c80a1a205dc\firmata_test.ino:
>   In member function 'virtual void test_beginPrintsVersion::once()':
>
> C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_c8217a5b56c170d64dfe4c80a1a205dc\firmata_test.ino:32:3:
>   warning: narrowing conversion of '249' from 'int' to 'char' inside { }
>   [-Wnarrowing]
>
> };
>
> ^
>
> Multiple libraries were found for "Firmata.h"  Used:
>   C:\Users\saurabh2836\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Firmata  Not used:
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\Firmata

I'm getting this error. I searched but found no conclusive answer. I'm using Windows 8 64bit and Firmata downloaded from http://www.firmata.org/.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is giving a lot of information. The warnings can be ignored but the "multiple libraries" indicates that there is at least two copies of Firmata installed. Check (search) that you have not got several downloads of Firmata. Worst case reinstall to clean up that.

Cheers!

Comment: but what about Category '' in library ArduinoUnit error what are the step to replace adruino unit library

Comment: That is from the library manager when reading the library.properties file. The category tag is not correct (actually missing) for ArduinoUnit. https://github.com/mmurdoch/arduinounit/blob/master/library.properties. It is a warning and can be ignored.

Comment: but i am not able to run the program for test firmata after reinstall it

Comment: But does it compile? This issue was about compiling it. Are there still compile warnings and errors? Did the "multiple libraries..." link error disappear? I was assuming that you had an installation problem.

Comment: no still the same issue

Comment: You have to remove one of the two libraries. Currently there is two copies of the library installed. Both get located and compile (according to the error message from the linker).

Comment: Did you still get: "Multiple libraries were found for "Firmata.h" Used: C:\Users\saurabh2836\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Firmata Not used: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\Firmata". The compiler is telling you where the two libraries are. Remove one of them.

Comment: i solved the issue of library loading double but now that firmata test program is not working i am not able to controller high/low from firmata to arduino